# Trigger system volume bar

Tags: android, volume

Is it possible by pressing a button in my `Activity` to make the volume bar appear? The volume bar is the view that appears when you press one of the hardware volume buttons.

Is there a API function to do this or do I have to recreate that view by hand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you call setStreamVolume, pass the flag FLAG_SHOW_UI
See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#FLAG_SHOW_UI

Answer (score 3):

Working code

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    AudioManager.ADJUST_SAME, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to turn sound on/off:

```kotlin
    val audio = getSystemService(getApplication(), Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
    audio.adjustStreamVolume(
        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
        AudioManager.ADJUST_SAME, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI
    )
}
```

It's worked.