# Android Bluetooth Earpiece Volume

Tags: android, bluetooth, volume

how can I programmatically set the system volume for voice call when using a bluetooth earpiece?

Using this:

```
mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, myVolume, 0);
```

when a call (using the Earpice) is in progress it doesn't change anything.

I searched a lot before posting, but can't find any hint on how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I also got in same problem and found out that, Android is using int 6 for bluetooth volume and not documented.

Just use **6** instead of AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL and try, It should work

Comment: awesome hint, frustrating that this is not documented. while it works, I have one problem with this: the volume control (the one that the system shows when you change the volume using volume up/down hardwre keys on the phone)  isn't shown - any way to fix this?

Comment: by the way, how did you find that out? you checked the source code? which source file exactly is it? thanks :-)

Comment: and here is how to show the volume control: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581722/trigger-system-volume-bar?rq=1 :-)

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf I checked logs for CS call and found it. Logs are printing those values :)

Comment: You are late with your reply :P No, seriously, thanks for it, even after that long time!

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf not a frequent SO user :)

Answer (score -1):

This will work.

```
mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(6, value, 0 /* flags, 0 = no flags */);
```