# Bluetooth hands free client volume control

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-4.4-kitkat, hfp

I have an android device acting as a hands free client device using hfp.

[Using the following code:](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/5.0.0_r1/com/android/bluetooth/hfpclient/)

I am able to receive a call and the speakers and mic are working as expected.

My problem is that I can't seem to control the volume.

I tried using the following lines of code to find the correct stream, but none of them seem to work.

I tracked the volume command being sent from the phone to the client in the class `HeadsetClientStateMachine` , line #1822 in the following link: [HeadsetClientStateMachine from lolipop](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/5.0.0_r1/com/android/bluetooth/hfpclient/HeadsetClientStateMachine.java/?v=source)

```
case EVENT_TYPE_VOLUME_CHANGED:
    if (event.valueInt == HeadsetClientHalConstants.VOLUME_TYPE_SPK) {
        mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_BLUETOOTH_SCO, event.valueInt2, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        mVgsFromStack = true;
       Log.d(TAG, "EventVolumeChange STREAM_BLUETOOTH_SCO value: " + event.valueInt2);
    }
```

When I change the volume on the phone, I do see the log showing the updated value of the sound, which means that the `setStreamVolume()` method is being called, but the volume doesn't change.

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?

**EDIT:**

I am still looking for an answer and am now looking toward the audio HAL implementation. I suspect that the link between the HAL and the audio driver is somehow incorrect... I don't know much about low level implementation and am not sure what I should be looking for.

Comment: I forgot to mention: The HFPClient classes are not present in Kitkat: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/core/java/android/bluetooth/ they were back ported from lollipop, thus the code I use is the same as the lollipop implementation.

Comment: It could be, I m investigating in that direction right now. In parallel I was wondering if there was a known behavior of android with HFP client profile that prevents it from controlling the volume.

Comment: The odd part is the sound works, the bluetooth volume change event is being passed, and the setStreamVolume() method is being called the way it should be. It just can't seem to adjust the volume...

Comment: I've tested on different hardware, but all with the same architecture as it's the only one that my custom rom supports...

Comment: I wonder if this has anything related to the problem: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/libhardware/+/73b8a7414afa5ee3f006468f287695d9c2054d76

Comment: if it is playing a , did you tried the specific stream like `STREAM_MUSIC`?music.

Comment: In my experience, on some devices bluetooth headset volume can be changed only using headset controls. I'm in posession of one such android phone actually.

Comment: @VallyN this is called absolute volume control and is part of AVRCP profile. It's unfortunately not the case in my problem.

Comment: It should be audiomanager issue; can you paste some logs?

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try below.
I did not try myself but sounds similar problem if I understand correctly:

[Android Bluetooth Earpiece Volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472613/android-bluetooth-earpiece-volume)

"*Android is using int 6 for bluetooth volume and not documented.
Just use 6 instead of AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL and try, It should work*"

I assume for you will be to replace AudioManager.STREAM_BLUETOOTH_SCO with 6.

Good luck, I hope it will work.