# Simulating Infotainment Device as a HFP Client

Tags: android, bluetooth, hfp

Android lollipop is running on my target board.

My board and phone are paired over blue-tooth.If I get a call on my android phone, how can I simulate it with my board for answering & rejecting the call?

At this point of time when I am getting call on  my phone HFP is working fine,

I just want to simulate it with Board UI for answering and rejecting the call.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

config value in packages/app/Bluetooth/res/values/config.xml  and a hide class

```
<bool name="profile_supported_hfpclient">false</bool>
android.bluetooth.BluetoothHeadsetClient, this provides HFP client API, such as dial, accept call.
```

source:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/zQVDRlQt4DQ

Additionally you can find a lot more information in this question:
[Bluetooth hands free client volume control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32321794/bluetooth-hands-free-client-volume-control)