# How to increase and decrease the volume programmatically in Android

Tags: java, android, android-audiomanager

I created a music player app and I want to set the volume up/down programmatically. I want to implement two `Button`s to increase/decrease the volume and set to the media player.

**Activity**:

```
control = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.control);
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
control.setOnClickListener(pausePlay);
control.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
control id is my play and pause button :
{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (playPause) {
            control.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            media.stop();
            intialStage = false;
            playPause = false;

        } else {
            control.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
            if (intialStage) {
                new Player()
                        .execute("http://streaming.shoutcast.com/MUKILFMRADIO");
            } else {
                if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    mediaPlayer.start();
            }
            playPause = true;
        }
}
```

**Layout**:

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/control1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/decrement"
        android:layout_above="@+id/latestAddedSongs"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/musicArtistName" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/control"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/play"
        android:layout_above="@+id/latestAddedSongs"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/musicArtistName" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/control2"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/increment"
        android:layout_above="@+id/latestAddedSongs"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/musicArtistName" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want to manage mediaplayer volume? use `mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(3, paramAnonymousInt, 0)`

Comment: but how to set the function to my up and down button

Comment: show me the complete xml and complete java .. i.e edit your question

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Create an object for audio manager

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);


Button upButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upButton);
        upButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //To increase media player volume               
                audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
            }
        });
        
        Button downButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.downButton);
        downButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
                //To decrease media player volume
                audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);             
            }
        });
```

The above example used Button label

for volume up and down
code

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
                if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
                }
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
                if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

Comment: is this the volume of the system audio or the media volume only ?

Comment: @gumuruh It's the volume of "the most relevant stream", basically the same as the hardware keys control. The equivalent method for a specific stream is `adjustStreamVolume()`.

Answer (score 31):

Try below code

```
audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

seekbar.setMax(audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));

seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int newVolume, boolean b) {
    textview.setText("Media Volume : " + newVolume);
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, newVolume, 0);
  }

  @Override
  public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

  @Override
  public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!. It worked perfect. Simple and easiest answer.

Answer (score 8):

Below code worked great

There are several streams available in Android using which audio can be managed

```
 /** The audio stream for phone calls */
    public static final int STREAM_VOICE_CALL = AudioSystem.STREAM_VOICE_CALL;
    /** The audio stream for system sounds */
    public static final int STREAM_SYSTEM = AudioSystem.STREAM_SYSTEM;
    /** The audio stream for the phone ring */
    public static final int STREAM_RING = AudioSystem.STREAM_RING;
    /** The audio stream for music playback */
    public static final int STREAM_MUSIC = AudioSystem.STREAM_MUSIC;
    /** The audio stream for alarms */
    public static final int STREAM_ALARM = AudioSystem.STREAM_ALARM;
    /** The audio stream for notifications */
    public static final int STREAM_NOTIFICATION = AudioSystem.STREAM_NOTIFICATION;
    /** @hide The audio stream for phone calls when connected to bluetooth */
    public static final int STREAM_BLUETOOTH_SCO = AudioSystem.STREAM_BLUETOOTH_SCO;
    /** @hide The audio stream for enforced system sounds in certain countries (e.g camera in Japan) */
    public static final int STREAM_SYSTEM_ENFORCED = AudioSystem.STREAM_SYSTEM_ENFORCED;
    /** The audio stream for DTMF Tones */
    public static final int STREAM_DTMF = AudioSystem.STREAM_DTMF;
    /** @hide The audio stream for text to speech (TTS) */
    public static final int STREAM_TTS = AudioSystem.STREAM_TTS;
```

Depending on your need you can change the stream here is STREAM_MUSIC example :

You can get constant value using refelction from AudioSytem class:

```
 private int getStreamType(String streamName) {
        final String streamSourceClassName = "android.media.AudioSystem";
        int streamType = 0;
        try {
            streamType = (int) Class.forName(streamSourceClassName).getDeclaredField(streamName).get(null);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return streamType;
    }


audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

seekbar.setMax(audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));

seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int newVolume, boolean b) {
    textview.setText("Media Volume : " + newVolume);
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, newVolume, 0);
  }

  @Override
  public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

  @Override
  public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
});
```

Answer (score 6):

if your type is AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC： use this code ，follow phone volume button

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
        audio.adjustStreamVolume(
            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE,
            AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND | AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
        audio.adjustStreamVolume(
            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER,
            AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND | AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        return true;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Following up on solution of jesu, if you want to change volume within Service instead of Activity, replace:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

with:

```
AudioManager audioManager;
audioManager = (AudioManager) YourServiceName.this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 4):

This code will set the volume 100 instantly with no feedback to the user when buttonSES is pressed.

```
public void perform_actionSES(View v) {
Button buttonSES = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSES);

AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100, 0);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

fellow coders. I have tried to make the code as simple as possible as far as I can. I hope this is helpful for someone. Have a nice day!

I am using:
Android Studio 4.2.2
Build #AI-202.7660.26.42.7486908, built on June 24, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by N/A
Windows 10 10.0

For the MainActivity.java, here is the code.

```
package com.tutorial.android.mediaplayertest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private AudioManager audioManager;
    private Button play, pause, decVolume, incVolume;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // I want my media player instantiated as soon as the app starts
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test);

        // play button
        play = findViewById(R.id.play_button);
        play.setOnClickListener(view -> {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Music Start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            mediaPlayer.start();
        });

        // pause button
        pause = findViewById(R.id.pause_button);
        pause.setOnClickListener(view -> {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Pause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            mediaPlayer.pause();
        });


        audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        // volume down button
        decVolume = findViewById(R.id.volume_down);
        decVolume.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Volume down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
        });

        // volume up button
        incVolume = findViewById(R.id.volume_up);
        incVolume.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Volume up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
        });
    }


}
```

In case of activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pause_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pause" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/volume_down"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-" />

        <Button
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/volume_up"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AudioManager aManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);


Button buttonUp= (Button) findViewById(R.id.upButton);
        buttonUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
    enter code here

//To increase media player volume               
                `enter code here`aManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
            }
        });

        Button downButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.downButton);
        buttondown.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                aManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);             
            }
        });
```

Comment: Just posting source code may not be enough (although it may solve the problem). Please consider adding some explanation on why the code you're posting is supposed to resolve the issue.