# How to get the Android device current media type?

Tags: java, android, android-audiomanager

I am using the AudioManager in my service to control the media volume, but I can only control the media type, which I write in `setStreamVolume()`. I have tried to use `getRingerMode()` to get the media type, but the content is my service's.

```
int currentType = audioManager.getRingerMode();
int currentVoice = audioManager.getStreamVolume(currentType);

audioManager.setStreamVolume(currentType, currentVoice, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND | AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

How can I control the other apps volume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ref : [how to increase and decrease the volume programmatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40925722/how-to-increase-and-decrease-the-volume-programmatically-in-android)

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);


Button upButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upButton);
        upButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

//To increase media player volume               
                audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
            }
        });

        Button downButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.downButton);
        downButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

//To decrease media player volume
                audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);             
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Dewey Reed and Ashvin solanki.
I get a inspiretion from Ashvin solanki and Dewey Reed helps me read the Android Source.
To get the current media type ,can use 
`adjustVolume()` and set the `direction` value as `AudioManager.ADJUST_SAME`.
For Example :
`audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_SAME, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND| AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);`
Now the AudioControl Window showed,and has the current media type.