# Android Mediaplayer setVolume not work when I press volume button on moblie

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

---

I use MediaPlayer setVolume function to control the audio track volume, that is ok. but when I set Volume 0, then press the volume button, the volume is not 0. Why? please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The volume you are changing is the volume of that mediaplayer instance not the device. To change device volume you need to create the [AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager) Object and use it to change device volume. Example :

```
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);


Button upButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upButton);
        upButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

//To increase media player volume               
                audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
            }
        });

        Button downButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.downButton);
        downButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

//To decrease media player volume
                audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);             
            }
        });
```

You can look at this complete [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40926655/7910735) to override volume button from your device.